# Not able to work out the update_or_create method in django in posting data to the database

Tags: python, django

I am having a model that has several fields. This is my views.py:

```
def person(request): 
     customer=request.user.customer

     if request.method == "POST":
            hobbies=request.POST['hobbies']
            sports=request.POST['sports']
            school=request.POST['school']
            swimming=request.POST['swimming']
            
    
            details=Details.update_or_create(hobbies=hobbies,sports=sports,school=school,swimming=swimming)
    
            details.save()
```

This is **models.py**

```
class Details(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    swimming=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False)
    sports=models.CharField(max_length=300,null=False)
    hobbies=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False)
    school=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False)
```

Whenever a customer enters the respective details in the form in html I want it to be saved if he is entering for the first time and if he already has his details entered earlier but wishes to edit them I want to update the same object instead of creating a new one. I tried using update_or_create method but its giving me error.
Please help me. Thnx

Comment: According to the documentation you have to write Details.objects.update_or_create(....) and not directly Details.update_or_create(...)

Comment: should it be details, created=Details.objects.update_or_create(..)  and what should be the arguments????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
details=Details.objects.update_or_create(customer=customer, defaults={'hobbies':hobbies,'sports':sports,'school':school,'swimming':swimming})
```

This might work for you. In the default section you need to pass a dictionary like above

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this so if any field is associated with the relation customer=request.user then it will be going to update the data and if there is not any then it will create a new
details=Details.update_or_create(customer=request.user, defaults={hobbies=hobbies,sports=sports,school=school,swimming=swimming})

NOTE: when you create, update method of the queryset you don't have to save in queryset like you did details.save()

Comment: What do I enter in the arguments.

Comment: I saw this on the docs but wasnt able to understand what I should keep in my arguments. For me I have a customer and if that customer already has added details but in future edits then I want to update so what should be my arguments

Comment: The fields are hobbies,sports,school,swimming

Comment: getting syntax error....Also shouldnt it be customer=request.user.customer  (These are two different models)

Comment: and also shouldnt there be  " , created " after details..What does created mean here.

Comment: When you use this when you try to print created after update or create method this will give you True or False so you know that from this method new table is created or updated